# Proof explanation: Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer such that $n, n+2$ and $n+4$ are all prime then $n=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Hey I'm studying for an exam and this was in the lecture notes and I've forgotten how to do it :/ any help would greatly be appreciated!

**Proof**

$n$ is prime.

If $n=2, n+2=4$ this is not prime, therefore it is a contradiction.

Suppose $n>3$

Since $n, n+2$ and $n+4$ are all primes bigger than 3, none of them are divisible by 3.

3 Cases: $n=3k\space\space\space n=3k+1\space\space\space n=3k+2$

Case 1: $n=3k$: This contradicts as $n$ is not divisible by $3$

Case 2: $n=3k_1: \space\space\therefore n+2=3k+3=3(k+1).$ This contradicts $n+2$ not divisible by 3

Case 3: $n=3k+2: \space\space\therefore n+4=3k+6=3(k+2).$ This contradicts $n+4$ not divisible by 3 (i.e. $n+4$ is no prime.

In all cases we have a contradiction $\therefore n\leq3 \therefore n=3$

I'm stuck on why he chose those three cases and why they aren't divisible by $3$ :/

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Why he chose those 3 cases: those are the only 3 cases, either a number is of the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ or $3k+2$ - if it was $3k+3$, then this is $3(k+1)=3k'$, so is of the same form as the first case.

Comment: Why they aren't divisible by $3$: because you know each of those three numbers is prime, and so only divisible by 1 and itself. So the only prime that is divisible by $3$ is $3$ itself, and you've assumed $n>3$, so also $n+2>3$, $n+4>3$. So none of them are equal to $3$, and so not divisible by it.

Answer (score 1):

One member of $\{n,n+2,n+4\}$ is divisible by $3$ iff one member of $\{n,n+2, (n+4)-3\}$ is divisible by $3$ iff one member of $\{n,n+1,n+2\}$ is divisible by $3.$ Which  occurs, because the residues of $n,n+1,n+2$ modulo $3$ are three different members of the set $\{0,1,2\}$.

So if $\{n, n+2,n+4\}$ is a set of primes and one of them is divisible by $3$ then one of them is equal to $3.$ But $n+4=3\implies n<0$ and $n+2=3 \implies n=1$. So  the only possibility is $n=3, n+2=5,n+4=7.$

Comment: Generally,if $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then one member of $\{n+xa:0\leq x\leq (b-1)\}$ is divisible by $b.$  (Here,we have $a=2,b=3$).